# How can I include single quotes surrounding a value coming from an environment variable into a PostgreSQL statement

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, psql, amazon-linux-2

This line of command I picked from one of my `bash` scripts I am trying to use to automate some initial setup of a PostgreSQL database in an Amazon Linux machine.

I have the environment variable named `TEST_PASSWORD` contains the value `TestSecret`. I need to pass this value in the SQL statement with single quotes like `'TestSecret'`.

So, as expected, it works in in **Method-1**, but not in **Method-2** or **Method-3** as showing below:

**Method-1:**

```
[root@host ~]# psql -U postgres -c "create user testuser with encrypted password 'TestSecret';"
CREATE ROLE
```

**Method-2:**

```
[root@host ~]# psql -U postgres -c "create user testuser with encrypted password $TEST_PASSWORD;"
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TestSecret"
LINE 1: create user testuser with encrypted password TestSecret;
                                                     ^
```

**Method-3:**

```
[root@host ~]# psql -U postgres -c "create user testuser with encrypted password \'$TEST_PASSWORD\';"
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: create user testuser with encrypted password \'TestSecret\';
                                                     ^
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial answer is: just replace the password itself, and keep everything else as you had it in your working command:

```
psql -U postgres -c "create user testuser with encrypted password '$TEST_PASSWORD';"
```

HOWEVER, this leaves you vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://bobby-tables.com/). There is no good way to fight against it in the command line. You can homebrew your own solution like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25059107/240443), or you can delegate the job to another language, one that supports parametrised queries.

Comment: Uh! I was sure that the `$TEST_PASSWORD` variable won't be evaluated if I use single quotes around it like `'TEST_PASSWORD'`, but I was wrong. Just checked with  `echo psql -U postgres -c "create user testuser with encrypted password '$TEST_PASSWORD';"`. Thank you!

Comment: The single quotes are themselves quoted (by the double quotes), so they lose their quotiness - they're just another character in the string. The only characters with superpowers inside double quotes (that I can think of) are `$` and `!`.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes around the environment variable reference

```
psql -U postgres -c "create user testuser with encrypted password '$TEST_PASSWORD';"
```